# Mobile bootstrap menu doesn't open

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, mobile, menu

I have a problem with the mobile navigation menu (bootstrap) which doesn't open now and I don't understand where this problem comes from. I'm using WordPress and I haven't change anything about the menu. Could you help me please?

[www.x4v1.com/cecile/](http://www.x4v1.com/cecile/)

The mobile menu (under 800 pixel width) doesn't open.

The problem has come after I created a child theme.

Comment: The menu opens just fine (tested on chrome and safari), clean your cache and refresh the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a mistake from my browser, the problem is solved. Thank you @MikeStardust !
I just have uninstall and reinstall chrome and now it work.